# Async "not expected" result

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await

I'm trying to understand how `async` works. All the examples I've seen use `asyncio.sleep`, but I would like to get an example without that. Below I have provided a simple example to demonstrate my confusion regarding how async/await works.

```
import asyncio
import time

from functools import wraps

def timing_async(f):
    @wraps(f)
    async def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        start = time.perf_counter()
        val = await f(*args, **kwargs)
        end = time.perf_counter()
        print(f"Async function {f.__qualname__} finished in {end - start:.2f} seconds")
        return val
    
    return inner

  
async def _simple_count(n=10000000):
    return [i for i in range(n)]

@timing_async
async def simple_count(n=100000000):
    t = await _simple_count(n)
    return t

@timing_async
async def sleep_short():
    await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
    return 10


@timing_async
async def sleep_long():
    await asyncio.sleep(0.2)
    return 20

async def main():
    tasks = [sleep_long(), sleep_short(),sleep_short()]
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```

If I run the `main` function, I will get back:

```
Async function sleep_short finished in 0.11 seconds
Async function sleep_short finished in 0.11 seconds
Async function sleep_long finished in 0.20 seconds
    
[20, 10, 10]
```

which looks sensible, since `sleep_short` takes shorter time to complete. However, if I define the function:

```
async def main():
    tasks = [simple_count(), sleep_short(), sleep_short()]
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```

I will get this output:

```
Async function simple_count finished in 4.18 seconds
Async function sleep_short finished in 0.10 seconds
Async function sleep_short finished in 0.10 seconds
```

which implies (?) that the `simple_count` coroutine is completed first, even though it is much slower to `sleep_short`.

I am pretty sure this is due to my misconception of how async/await works, so I would appreciate it, if you could help me understand this concept better through this example.

Comment: Why is main() async as well?

Comment: @RoeyMichaeli To be honest, I don't really know. This is how the main function is usually defined in similar examples I've seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asynchronous functions allow you to run concurrent tasks, i.e. coroutines, that yield control back to the caller at certain points. Concurrent execution is by no means parallelization. For the latter you'll want to use threads or processes. Since `_simple_count()` only performs one lengthy task without ever yielding back control to the calling function, it will block other concurrent tasks until it is done, since you literally await its result in the timing decorator's wrapper.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply, I am not very familar with all these, but I managed to find some solution to it.